# Runtime polymorphism in C

Tags: c

Can someone please give me a simple explanation of how to achieve or emulate run-time polymorphism in C.

Also, is this a valid example of runtime-polymorphism:

```
void fred(){
  printf("Fred here!\n"); 
}

void john(){
  printf("John here\n");
}

void barbara ( void (*function_ptr)() ){
  (*function_ptr)();
}

int main(){
  barbara (fred);
  barbara (john);
  return 0;
}
```

The function barbara dynamically calls either `john()` or `fred()`. Is this what runtime polymorphism **exactly** is?

Comment: Step #1: *Research key concepts*

Comment: What is runtime? You alredy know compile time what it is calling :D

Comment: @user2864740 Appreciate ur concern !

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 1):

> The function barbara dynamically calls either john() or fred().

No, it doesn't. `barbara()` calls whichever function you pass it as a parameter. `barbara()` does exactly the same thing no matter what you pass it -- namely, it executes the function that you pass as a parameter.

> Is this what runtime polymorphism exactly is?

**No.** If `barbara()` looked at the parameter and changed its behavior based on some features (especially the type) of the parameter, then you'd be closer to polymorphism.